#  Nucleus  and  center  of  certain  non  power associative  algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I am  looking  for  an  example  of  a  noncommutative  and non power  associative  n - dimensional  algebra  $A$  with $N(A)=Z(A)$, where $N(A)$  is  the  nucleus  and  $Z(A)$ the  center. All  the  examples  coming  to  my  mind  are  algebras  with $Z(A)\subseteq N(A)$

Thank  you

Answer (score 2):

I think the following example works.  Take an algebra $A$ (say, over $\mathbb{Z}$) with basis $\{ a, b, c \}$ and with products defined by putting $cb = c^2 = b$, and all other products of basis elements equal to $a$.  Then $(cc)c = bc = a$, while $c(cc) = cb = c$, so $A$ is not power-associative and non-commutative.  But the centre and nucleus are equal (to $\mathbb{Z}a$).