# Linking  associative  algebras  with  nonassociative  algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Is  the  following  statement  interesting  or  even  trivial ?

- For  every $n$ - dimensional  associative  algebra  $A$  over  a  field  $F$  there  is  a  $n +1$ - dimensional  nonassociative  algebra $V_A$ over $F$ with  the  following properties :

$1.$ $V_A$  is  non commutative and  non power associative !

$2.$ $A$ is  isomorphic  to $N(V_A)$, where $N(V_A)$ is  the  nucleus  of  $V_A$.

$3.$ If  $n +1$ is  odd  then  $Z(V_A ) = N(V_A)$, where $Z(V_A)$  is  the  center  of  $V_A$.

Ps - Sorry guys I  have  changed  the  formulation  few  times.The  last  change  was  due  to  a  typo, I meant  $V_A$  to  be  of  dimension $n + 1$ ! I  will  now  stop, thanks  for  all  the  replies...

Thank you

Comment: This is simply not an interesting statement. If $V_A$ would have any reasonable *positive* property rather than just non(power)associativity and noncommutativity, it might be of some use. Negative properties hardly interest anyone here (which is the reason why people misunderstood your "nonassociative" as "not necessarily associative" first!).

Comment: Dear Serfo, I would like to make two side comments: 1. when you change the formulation of the question in a sensible way, please keep track of the original formulation so that people who read the answers that were posted before your edits understand the discussion. 2. it seems that you have posted a different but similar question a few days ago under a different pseudo (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81878/nucleus-and-center-of-certain-non-power-assoc) without paying so much attention to the answer that was given. I might be totally wrong but it sounds a bit unfriendly. 

Comment: @darij: I strongly disagree with what you said. On the contrary, requiring non-associativity often limits the possibilities enormously! For instance, consider alternative division rings. If they are associative, then there are heaps of them, too many to classify. But if you impose non-associativity, there is only one class: the 8-dimensional Cayley-Dickson algebras (a.k.a. octonion algebras).

Comment: What if $n=0$ and $A$ is the zero algebra?  Your statement seems to be false in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be trivial: take $V_A:=A$.

EDIT: as it has been reformulated, the question has to be answered negatively now.

If you require $A$ and $V_A$ to have the same dimension $n$, and you ask that there exists a triple $(x,y,z) $ in $V_A$ such that $(xy)z\neq x(yz)$, then $N(V_A)\subsetneq V_A$ and thus $dim(N(V_A))<n$. So there is no hope to have  $A=N(V_A)$ even at the level of vector spaces.

Comment: Dear  Damien thanks  for  the  reply  but  let  say $V_A : \neq A$. Don`t  forget  the  assumption  is  $A$ associative  while  $V_A$ non associative.

Comment: Then the question does not make sens for me. It seems to me that associative algebras are examples of non-associative algebras. 

To be short, you have a functor $N:non-As-alg\to As-alg$ and you are looking for an adjoint to it (which is nothing but the forgetful functor $As-alg\to non-As-alg$). 

Comment: Dear  Damien  let  say  I  am  old  school  guy ( I do  not  use  categorical  concepts at all ) ! 

"It seems to me that associative algebras are examples of non-associative algebras " 

Well  allow  me  to  use  the following  " old school set  theoretic  " definition :

- An  algebra  over  a  field  $F$  is  associative  if $a(bc) = (ab)c$ for  all  $a,b, c \in A$, otherwise $A$  is  non associative ( i.e, $a(bc) =(ab)c $  does  not  hold  in  general !

Comment: @Serfo: my understanding is that people generally use "non-associative algebra" to mean "algebra that is not _necessarily_ associative." 

Comment: DamienC, I don't think an adjoint is what is being sought here.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: agreed. That was a strenghtening of my understanding of the original question (where I thought that "non-associative" meant "non necessarily associative" - for that context I think that the right question to ask is the existence of an adjoint to the functor $N$). 

Comment: @DamienC I  apologise  for  any  incovenience!Also there was  a  typo  on  the  last  reformulation : The  dimension  of  $V_A$  meant  to  be  $n+1$  not  $n$!! 

Comment: @Serfo. OK, thank you for your comment. 

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not convinced the question isn't trivial. Let $A$ be an associative algebra over a field $F$, and let $N$ be any nonassociative (in Serfo's particular sense of the word) $F$-algebra disjoint from $A$ with trivial nucleus. Then the Cartesian product $A\times N$ naturally inherits the structure of an $F$-algebra, and with this structure $A\times N$ is nonassociative and has nucleus (canonically?) isomorphic to $A$.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: This answer no longer (I think) applies to the question as it has been edited.

Comment: I should add that I am assuming, here, that algebras need not be unital; otherwise there is no algebra with trivial nucleus. Even then, I think, some similarly straightforward construction would probably still work (maybe adjoin new nonassociating objects $x, y, z$, and ensure that no new element of the algebra is in the nucleus?).